# WinRt C# HttpClient SendAsync does not return

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I am creating a Metro App that makes a HTTP Post request to a webserver to obtain JSON data.  Initially I use the same code to logon to the web server and the HTTP Post request returns fine.  It is only later that I run into an issue where the code hangs when I call the SendAsync() method.

I used wireshark to view the network traffic and I did see the server returning a response.  So I am not sure why the call is not completing.  Anyone have any ideas?

Here is the code I am using:

```
var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpHandler.CookieContainer = __CookieJar;
var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler);

UserAgentDetails userAgent = UserAgentDetails.GetInstance();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd(userAgent.UserAgentString);

foreach (string key in __colHeaders)
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(key, __colHeaders[key]);

var content = new StringContent(postData);
if (contentType != null && contentType.Length > 0)
    content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);

var requestMsg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(url));
requestMsg.Content = content;
requestMsg.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked = true;
var responseMsg = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMsg);
// no return from method after logon
```

Comment: Does anything change when you dispose your `HttpClient` instances?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried wrapping the HttpClient in a `using` block, but still same issue.

Comment: Have you actually verified that a HTTP Post using other methods (like say Fiddler etc) actual give you a valid response to the url you are using?

Comment: Yes, and I see the response coming back...

Comment: I figured it out... The request ended up being run on the UI thread and the whole post request was wrapped in a synchronizer.  Once I change the event to async and then got rid of the synchronizer, everything worked.